# Alternating sum of binomial coefficients $\sum_{k=0}^{49}(-1)^k \binom{99}{2k} = -2^{49}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, alternating-expression

How can you prove that $$\sum_{k=0}^{49} \binom{99}{2k}(-1)^k = -2^{49}?$$

A more general formula seems to be $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n + 1}{2k}(-1)^k$

For $n = 0:$ it equals $2^0$
For $n = 1: -2^1$
For $n = 2: -2^2$
For $n = 3: 2^3$
For $n = 4: 2^4$
For $n = 5: -2^5$
For $n = 6: -2^6$
For $n = 7: 2^7$
etc.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics where it have other meanings. Use `\cdot` ($\cdot$), `\times` ($\times$) or ideally just use simple juxtaposition.

Comment: $2^n=2^n-0^n=(1+1)^n-(1-1)^n=\sum{n\choose k}-\sum{n\choose k}(-1)^k$ should get you started.

Comment: How to write $(-1)^k = x^{2k}$, to match the $2k$ in the binomial coefficient? $x=i$ or $-i$. Here only the even $2k$ terms appear; how to introduce the odd terms? By averaging the conjugates: $\frac12 \left[(1+i)^{99}+(1-i)^{99}\right] = \Re\left[(1+i)^{99}\right] = \ldots$

Answer (score 2):

Use binomial theorem as
$$F(x)=\frac{(1+x)^{2n+1}+(1-x)^{2n+1}}{2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {2n+1 \choose 2k} x^{2k}$$
Then take$x=i$, to get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {2n+1 \choose 2k} (-1)^{2k}=F(i)=\frac{(1+i)^{2n+1}+(1-i)^{2n+1}}{2}=2^{n+1/2}\cos[(2n+1)\pi/4]n$$
where we have used $(1\pm i)=\sqrt{2}[\cos(\pi/4)\pm i\sin(\pi/4)]$  and demoivre's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

How to write $(-1)^k = x^{2k}$, to match the $2k$ in the binomial coefficient? $x=i$ or $-i$.

Here only the even $2k$ terms appear; how to introduce the odd terms? By averaging the conjugates: $\frac12 \left[(1+i)^{99}+(1-i)^{99}\right] = \Re\left[(1+i)^{99}\right] = \ldots$

Combining these two ideas,

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{49}\binom{99}{2k}(-1)^k &= \sum_{k=0}^{49}\binom{99}{2k}i^{2k}\\
&= \Re\left[\sum_{h=0}^{99}\binom{99}h i^h\right] &&(h=2k)\\
&= \Re\left[(1+i)^{99}\right]\\
&= \left(\sqrt2\right)^{96}\Re\left[(1+i)^3\right]\\
&= \left(\sqrt2\right)^{96}\left(1-3\right)\\
&= -2^{49}
\end{align*}$$